# Python Error 500 conexión FTP (activo) usando ftplib

Tags: python, python-3.x

les comento que tengo un error que me rompe la cabeza...

Tengo que conectarme a un FTP vía python 3, estoy utilizando la librería ftplib. Resulta que el servidor FTP acepta conexiones en modo activo, al indicar que tiene que ser modo activo me da error, si no uso el modo activo me da timeout.
Usando FileZilla compruebo que puedo acceder ok al FTP en modo activo.

```
import ftplib

site = "XXX.XXX.X.X"
puerto = "21"
username = "XXXXXXX"
password= "XXXXXXX"

ftp = FTP(host=site, user=username, passwd=password)
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
ftp.set_pasv(False)
ftp.login(user=username, passwd=password)
ftp.dir()
```

En la consola recibo el siguiente error al pasar el parámetro ftp.set_pasv(False) para ponerlo en modo activo.

```
*cmd* 'USER XXXXXXX'
*put* 'USER XXXXXXX\r\n'
*get* '331 Password required for XXXXXXX.\n'
*resp* '331 Password required for XXXXXXX.'
*cmd* 'PASS ******'
*put* 'PASS ******\r\n'
*get* '230 User XXXXXXXlogged in.\n'
*resp* '230 User XXXXXXXlogged in.'
*cmd* 'TYPE A'
*put* 'TYPE A\r\n'
*get* '200 Type set to A.\n'
*resp* '200 Type set to A.'
*cmd* 'PORT 172,19,55,105,174,27'
*put* 'PORT 172,19,55,105,174,27\r\n'
*get* '500 Invalid PORT Command.\n'
*resp* '500 Invalid PORT Command.'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "FTPtest.py", line 14, in <module>
    ftp.dir()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 558, in dir
    self.retrlines(cmd, func)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 451, in retrlines
    with self.transfercmd(cmd) as conn, \
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 382, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 363, in ntransfercmd
    with self.makeport() as sock:
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 311, in makeport
    resp = self.sendport(host, port)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 290, in sendport
    return self.voidcmd(cmd)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 280, in voidcmd
    return self.voidresp()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 253, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 248, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 500 Invalid PORT Command.
```

Si no paso el ftp.set_pasv(False) recibo timeout porque si o si debe ser en modo activo.

Se les ocurre que puede estar pasando? O existe alguna otra librería que pueda probar?

/******************************* UPDATE *******************************\

En respuesta a @ChemaCortes..
Acabo de probar con el código de ejemplo que me brindaste, adicionalmente agregue un ftp.dir() al final y ahí es donde se da el error. Mirando bien los errores anteriores me di con que pasa lo mismo, se loguea al FTP pero da error cuando paso un dir.

```
 with ftplib.FTP() as ftp:
    ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
    ftp.set_pasv(False)
    ftp.connect(host=site)
    ftp.login(user=username, passwd=password)
    ftp.dir()

*get* '230 User xxxxxx logged in.\n'
*resp* '230 User xxxxxx logged in.'

    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "FTPtest.py", line 13, in <module>
    ftp.dir() <---- ACA DA ERROR
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 558, in dir
    self.retrlines(cmd, func)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 451, in retrlines
    with self.transfercmd(cmd) as conn, \
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 382, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 363, in ntransfercmd
    with self.makeport() as sock:
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 311, in makeport
    resp = self.sendport(host, port)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 290, in sendport
    return self.voidcmd(cmd)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 280, in voidcmd
    return self.voidresp()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 253, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 248, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 500 Invalid PORT Command.
```

/******************************* UPDATE *******************************\

Me estoy conectado a una IP publica, no es un localhost. Es muy raro, el server acepta la conexión desde FileZilla (modo activo) y puedo hacer cualquier cosa casi. También acepta la conexión desde Python, pero cuando mando un .dir() da error 500. File "FtpTest.py", line 15, in  ftp.dir() ftplib.error_perm: 500 Invalid PORT Command.
Revise mi firewall, no hay restricciones. El log de FileZilla no acusa nada, porque no da errores. Y como bien dijiste, dudo que sea el servidor, porque acepta listarme directorios y archivos con filezilla, pero desde python no.

/**************************** UPDATE SOLVED ****************************\

Utilizando el ejemplo de @ChemaCortes funciona.
Al mismo tiempo el problema no radicaba en el código si no en la configuración del server FTP, este no me estaba aceptando transferencia de datos vía VPN porque por algún bloqueo o la misma VPN se perdían los datos. Al poner el script en el posible servidor de producción se ejecutaron de manera correcta todas las operaciones que le solicite. Agradecido! Saludos y Felicidades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por defecto, la instancia FTP se crea con el modo pasivo activo. Para cuando lo intentas cambiar con `.set_pasv()`, ya ha intentado antes hacer la conexión y ha fallado.

Para activar el modo activo, hay que crear la instancia sin pasarle ningún argumento:

```py
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.set_pasv(False)
ftp.connect(host=site)
ftp.login(user=username, passwd=password)
...
```

Mi recomendación es que hagas la conexión en un bloque `with`, con lo que te aseguras que la conexión siempre se cerrará al final:

```py
import ftplib

with ftplib.FTP() as ftp:
    ftp.set_pasv(False)
    ftp.connect(host=site)
    ftp.login(user=username, passwd=password)
    ...
```

Comment: Hola @ChemaCortes
Me acabo de dar cuenta que se loguea, pero el problema nace cuando hago un ftp.dir() por ejemplo. Ahí se dan todos los errores. Me pasa lo mismo con tu código de ejemplo, sea con with o sin el.

Comment: Hice una actualización del post por si sirve de algo. @chema

Comment: El modo activo usa los puertos 21, para control, y 20, para transferir datos. Es casi seguro que tu firewall esté bloqueando el acceso al puerto 20. No sé porqué te funciona Filezilla, aunque por defecto siempre usa el modo pasivo.

Comment: Claro, con FileZilla si funciona, tuve que decirle que usara modo activo obviamente si no me patea. Te refieres al firewall de mi pc o al del servidor?

Comment: No creo que sea el servidor. Puede que el bloqueo sea cosa del router, aunque también es probable que del firewall de tu pc (con IP 172.19.55.105, no localhost). Revisa el log de filezilla a ver qué respuestas está dando el servidor.

Comment: Es que me estoy conectado a una IP publica, no es un localhost.

Es muy raro, el server acepta la conexión desde FileZilla (modo activo) y puedo hacer cualquier cosa casi.

También acepta la conexión desde Python, pero cuando mando un .dir() da error 500.

File "FtpTest.py", line 15, in <module>
    ftp.dir()
ftplib.error_perm: 500 Invalid PORT Command.

Revise mi firewall, no hay restricciones. El log de FileZilla no acusa nada, porque no da errores.
Y como bien dijiste, dudo que sea el servidor, porque acepta listarme directorios y archivos, pero desde python no.

Comment: Resuelto... Resulta que estaba accediendo desde una VPN, me posicione en el servidor donde va a ir este script lo ejecute y funciono!
Definitivamente es algo del Firewall del server, al cual no tengo acceso, pero en fin, problema resuelto! Gracias @ChemaCortes, muchas gracias!